# Waypoints not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I want to animate my h1 tag (along with others later) to show up in a sliding motion when the page scrolls to its parent element (#team - that's the containing div).

This is the code. If instead of waypoints I use a click event, it works, but this way nothing happens. I put the path to Waypoints after jQuery of course.

```
$(function() {
    $('#team').waypoint(function() {
        $('.h1-slide').animate({
            bottom: 0
        }, 2000, 'easeOutExpo');
    });
});
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Mind setting up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I'm not sure if a fiddle will work here, how can I include Waypoints in it? 

Anyway, I've tried with the most basic examples (ex. a notification when getting to the div) and it's not working either, so I think there's a problem with Waypoints fireing in general, not in this specific example only.

Comment: Without **some** sort of example we can't tell what wrong. It's possible that the JQ code is correct but something else is breaking. Perhaps a link to a live page?

Comment: It's not yet live and far from that for now. How can I define the jQuery library and make Waypoints work in jsfiddle? I've tried just pasting the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: over on the left you can select your jquery version under framework and extensions... there is also a section for external resources

Comment: What JS errors do you see in console?